# How to show selected option from spinner in which we fetch data from API with Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-spinner

I want to  make a spinner using retrofit 2, I successfully fetch my data and show it in spinner but when I try to show the selected option in textview it shows me blank here is my onResponse:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ListModel> call, Response<ListModel> response) {
    ListModel data = response.body();
    if (data.getStatuscode().equals("100")) {
        category.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.getData().size(); i++ ) {
                String options = 
                String.valueOf(data.getData().get(i).getName());
                category.add(options);
        }adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category);        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);selectoptions.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


@Override
public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<ListModel> call, Throwable t) {

}
```

Here is my on item selected function -

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    example.setText(String.valueOf(item));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the adapter inside the for loop? Have you tried populating the category array first (with the for loop) and then do the adapter initialization and setting after the loop?

Comment: ya, I already tried that way and I also update It in question now. It shows fetch data properly in spinner but it does not show a selected option in public void on item selected through string.

Comment: You are still not setting the adapter on the spinner

Comment: You also need to set spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()

Comment: Thank you it's done but how can I set a default option like choose or select text or hint for the spinner